# Как можно создать экземпляр префаба и поместить его в конкретный раздел в иерархии? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Каким образом я могу через код создать экземпляр префаба и поместить его в нужное мне место, в иерархии unity?

Comment: [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)

Comment: Instantiate может принимать параметр родителя. Ссылка дана выше

Comment: @МаксимФисман, Я назначил переменную с типом GameObject, в качестве родителя префаба. Юнити говорит, что нельзя преобразовать GameObject в Transform

Comment: Потому что родителем должен быть TRANSFORM! Если у вас есть GameObject, то его Transform можно получить через `gameObject.transform`

Comment: @МаксимФисман, Спасибо!